# ios - In-app purchase failure in active application

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app with in-app purchase. I think I made all the settings right. I tested my application on XCode and I did not have any problems. I sent my application to AppStore. It was reviewed and approved along with the first in-app purchase feature. My application currently in the market. But I have an important problem.

When I download my application from the appStore, in-app purchasing is not working. There is no problem when I test the same version through XCode.

for example (I'm using SwiftyStoreKit):

```
SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo([bundleID + "." + purchase.rawValue], completion: {
        result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationFinished()

        self.myInfo = self.getInfo(result: result)
    })


func getInfo (result : RetrieveResults) -> String {

    if let product = result.retrievedProducts.first {
        let priceString = product.localizedPrice!
        return  ("\(product.localizedTitle) - \(product.localizedDescription) - \(priceString)")
    }
    else if let invalidProductID = result.invalidProductIDs.first {
        return "Invalid Product \(invalidProductID)"
    } else {
        let errorString = result.error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unkown Error"
        return ("Product Error \(errorString)")

    }
}
```

When I experiment with XCode, I get information about the in-app purchasing feature. However, the application I downloaded from AppStore returns an invalid product.

Note: In-app purchasing feature approved and Cleared for Sale is checked.

In summary: In-app purchase works in test phase but does not work in appstore active app.

I do not think the problem is in the codes, but I do not understand what the problem is.

I will be very happy if you can help. Thank you.

Comment: And the problem resolved spontaneously. So you need to be patient. About 7-8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an iTunes Connect IAP release delay issue. My app was marked ready for sale at the same time my IAP was, but it took about half a day to stop responding with the "invalid product" error. If all worked in the sandbox, then patience is key!

Answer (score -1):

All the tutorials for the implementation of iAP are kind of wrong, regarding the productID implementation:

Simple replace `bundleID + "." + purchase.rawValue` with `purchase.rawValue`